# Meaning of "to be on the top side of the grass"

Tags: idioms

What is the meaning of this sentence:

> To be healthy as long as you're on the top side of the grass

I specifically mean the phrase *on the top side of the grass*.

Comment: This isn't really an idiom. What do you conclude the phrase means? How might it contrast to being under the grass?

Comment: The Green Side of the Grass is a funny song about growing old and the aging process that we go through in life. I’m thankful each day I wake up because it means another day on top of the green side of the grass.http://biggeekdad.com/2013/05/green-side-of-the-grass/

Comment: I don't recall this exact form, but obviously if you're on the ***top*** side of the grass, you're ***not dead and buried*** - you're still alive, so it would be good to be healthy as well. The speaker may also be influenced by *the grass is always greener **on the other side*** (which has nothing to do with burial).

Answer (score 1):

> - My goal in this book is to show you how you can cut down on your intake of toxins and detoxify your life so that you can enjoy the best possible health for as long as you're *on the top side of the grass*. - Detox Diets For Dummies, Gerald Don Wootan, Matthew Brittain Phillips
> - Don’t ever take my training time away from me. As long as you find me *on the top side of the grass*, I will train. - a site on crime and defense training.
> - None of us know for sure how long our lives will last/Try not to worry, learn how to laugh/For I know life ain't easy, we can't relive the past. /But it sure is nice to be *on the top side of the grass*./ Yeah, it sure is a real fine day, *on the top side of the grass*. Top Side of the Grass, music and lyrics by Mike Webb

For a saying I never heard before, there are a surprising number of hits on Google.  Clearly, all of them have the same meaning: while you're living. In the strictest sense, it is an idiom; just not one that was common to me.